# For Ignite, how can I use the same classes in different packages without overriding Marshaller?

Tags: java, ignite

Hello and thanks in advance!

I'm tring to use embedded Ignite when app projects have different packages like `"com.eta.one"` and `"com.eta.another"`.

I set `BinaryTypeConfiguration` for `"com.eta.*"` with `new BinaryBasicNameMapper(true)`. So, I enable simple class name resolution with `true`. And I was hoping this is how it should work. But it doesn't work for me.

It seems like I can specify my own Marshaller, but it's marked as 'deprecated'.
I've solved same problem while testing Hazelcast (~ similar technology) setting 'global serializer'.

I use code below in two projects in different packages.

```
String packageWithModels = "com.eta.*";
BinaryTypeConfiguration binaryTypeConfiguration = new BinaryTypeConfiguration()
    .setTypeName(packageWithModels)
    .setIdMapper(new BinaryBasicIdMapper(true))
    .setNameMapper(new BinaryBasicNameMapper(true));
BinaryConfiguration binaryConfiguration = new BinaryConfiguration()
    .setTypeConfigurations(Collections.singleton(binaryTypeConfiguration));
IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration()
    .setBinaryConfiguration(binaryConfiguration);

Ignite ignite = Ignition.start(cfg);

IgniteCache<Integer, MyObject> cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache("myCacheMyObject");
MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
myObject.setText("Hello World!");

MyObject before = cache.get(1);
System.out.println("before:" + before);
cache.put(1, myObject);
MyObject after = cache.get(1);
System.out.println("after:" + after);
```

#### Question:

- Is there a way to do use same classes with different packages?
- Wondering if these classes can contain different sets of fields? In a
  different order?
- It would also be very nice if I can avoid manually
  registering all types. And it seems like a bad idea to use the
  deprecated `Marshaler` change feature.

#### Update 09.11.20 16:19:

I tried to use the global mapper as the @alamar suggested. So, `BinaryConfiguration` changed and `BinaryTypeConfiguration` removed:

```
BinaryConfiguration binaryConfiguration = new BinaryConfiguration()
                .setIdMapper(new BinaryBasicIdMapper(true))
                .setNameMapper(new BinaryBasicNameMapper(true));
```

But the situation didn't change. Still showing error `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.eta.one.MyObject` when `com.eta.another` project is subsequently launched. Really strange if this doesn't work specifically for java, although I don't understand where I could have gone wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`BinaryBasicNameMapper` should work - it's used by .Net plugin which works. I don't think that you can use wildcards in type name, so no `"com.eta.*"` for you. You can still set this mapper globally.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion! I tried but I faced with `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.eta.one.MyObject` again when start `com.eta.another` project. Really strange if this doesn't work specifically for java, although I don't understand where I could have gone wrong. I see wildcard here:  [link](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/data-modeling/binary-marshaller#configuring-binary-objects)